# get two values in select query based on different where condition and subtract them

Tags: mysql

I  have a table that looks like this. The same id1 can have more than one rows with different action values. However there can be one 'opened' and one 'merged' value for one id1 (not all id1 will have a row with 'merged' value but every id is guaranteed to have 'opened' value)

```
id_1    id2 id3     action      time                ext_id    
8131201 2   345886  opened      2012-01-19 00:24:55 5099318b1b66c0d7b200000c
8510820 2   345886  merge       2012-01-26 09:20:17 5099318b1b66c0d7b200000d
```

For those id1 which have a 'merged' value, I want to get the time difference between when it was opened and when it was merged in a single query. How might that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self join:

```
SELECT t.id_1, TIMEDIFF(t.time, t2.time) AS time_difference
FROM t
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t.id_1 = t2.id_1
WHERE t.action = 'opened'
AND t2.action = 'merge
```

So basically join the table to itself on id 1, where the first record is opened and the second is merge. Then find the difference in the times from each copy of the table, using TIMEDIFF.